# Does ClearType font rendering draw the same character exactly the same every time?

Tags: browser, fonts, ocr, cleartype

I am developing some OCR software for small on-screen fonts. The fonts are rendered in the browser. I notice that they are rendered with ClearType onto the screen and the letters in the words seem to be the same no matter where they are located on-screen, although I have not checked many cases, just some common cases.

For example in the following image the letter a is repeated twice, once at the beginning and nice later 3rd from the end. The letter a looks exactly the same, pixel for pixel. My question is, is the letter a always the same for the same font and same font size within ClearType rendering? Does the same apply for all letters within the same font?

[image]

[ClearType is here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might or it might not, depending upon the font, the size, and which version of ClearType is in use (and which application settings are applied for rendering). [Microsoft's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explanation of ClearType gets into this somewhat, and even shows an example where you can observe a case where two instances of a character do *not* render the same (see 'elle', on the right; both the 'e' and 'l' render differently in the second instance). This has to do with the use of fractional advance widths, which get resolved to the nearest 1/64th of a pixel. Thus you could potentially end up with many different instances of a single character (though as you can see, the differences are fairly subtle).

In short: I would not write anything that *depends* on any two instances of a character ending up exactly the same. They will be pretty similar, but not identical.